# Create windows process to delete any unwanted icons from the desktop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

IT has a process hidden somewhere deep on my system which automatically creates certain icons and shortcuts on  my desktop if they do not exist. (It may even exist solely on their systems, connecting to mine periodically to do this.) This means when I try to delete them, they are back within a couple of hours. This drives me nuts. I have all of the shortcuts and icons on my taskbar, and do not like having random crap on my desktop.

I would like to write something to run as a service which monitors the desktop every second or so, and deletes anything that shows up.

How would I go about doing this? In a relatively easy and straightforward manner? Would I use a bat file, or vbs script? How do I create a bat file to run as a service?

Comment: A simpler solution is to right-click the desktop, go to the View menu, and turn off the "Show desktop icons" option.

Comment: The "hidden process" is probably Group Policy Preferences creating desktop shortcuts that your company considers relevant for all their users. I suggest you talk to your IT department about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the "Hide protected operating system files" setting on (it is by default) you could try to just hide the icons with `ATTRIB +R +S +H "annoyingapp.lnk"`.

You can't just run anything as a service. You could perhaps use the [Srvany](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/137890/how-to-create-a-user-defined-service) tool to execute your script but I would imagine a [task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) that runs every now and then is a better fit for this issue.